# How to make the button centre aligned in all ios devices programmatically in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout

I am creating an app where I have created a button programmatically , But I am having problem where this button does not show perfectly in the center when viewed in other devices such as iphone8, 7, and so on... It shows perfectly on a iphone X. How to show my button perfectly in all devices?

Here is my code:

```
let button = RideRequestButton()

let dropoffLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 37.6213129, longitude: -122.3789554)
let builder = RideParametersBuilder()
builder.dropoffLocation = dropoffLocation
builder.dropoffNickname = "Your Dropoff Location"
button.rideParameters = builder.build()

button.center = view.center
view.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use autolayout constraints to center the button.

```
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(button)
    let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let centerYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([centerXConstraint, centerYConstraint])
```

Or you can set an autoresizing mask

```
    button.center = view.center
    button.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]'
```

Or if you are targeting iOS 9 and above you can use `NSLayoutAnchor`

```
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(button)
    button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: is it below my `button.center = view.center`, right?

Comment: For the autolayout example, it would be instead of your button.center code. The `addConstraint` calls add the `NSLayoutConstraint`s which will keep the button centered

Comment: Interesting way... Thank you for you're help.

Comment: Apple discourages the use of the `addConstraint` method. From Apple's docs: `When developing for iOS 8.0 or later, set the constraint’s isActive property to true instead of calling the addConstraint(_:) method directly. The isActive property automatically adds and removes the constraint from the correct view.` You can also use `NSLayoutConstraint.activate([centerXConstraint, centerYConstraint])` to activate them both simultaneously. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622523-addconstraint

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler Thanks for the heads up, I wasn't aware that that was discouraged. I've been using addConstraint for years with no ill effects, not sure why Apple is recommending the switch without deprecating the addConstraint method, but I'll follow the advice. Updated my post to reflect the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to programmatically set a button at the center of your view then you can use center property or by set frame :

Using center property

```
    let button = RideRequestButton()
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    button.frame.size.width = 200
    button.frame.size.height = 50
    button.center = self.view.center
    view.addSubview(button)
```

Using set frame by CGRect

```
    let button = RideRequestButton()
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    button.frame.size.width = 200
    button.frame.size.height = 50
    button.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2 - button.frame.size.width/2, y: self.view.frame.size.height/2 - button.frame.size.height/2, width: button.frame.width, height: button.frame.height)
    view.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before this line

```
button.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:view.frame.width,height:50)
button.center = view.center
```

you have to give the button a frame

Comment: awesome job! I got the point. It just needs a frame. Thank you @Sh_Khan